# Is a function within the loop-test portion of a FOR loop called on every iteration?

Tags: loops, for-loop

If a function is part of the loop-test in a FOR loop, is that function called on every iteration of the loop or only the first iteration to setup the loop.

e.g.

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(someString); i++) {
    // Do Something 
}
```

Is it better form to define a variable before the loop, whose value is the string length?

e.g.

```
int length = strlen(someString);

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, would it evaluate if you replaced your test expression with a function call:  `for (int i = 0; isDone(i); i++) { ... }`  I think you know the answer, so I think you know the answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the language (and if there is a method call as part of the test, and whether the compiler can determine if the method call will not change each iteration)

For instance, in some situations VB.NET evaluates once, c# evaluates each time.

There was a recent SO question that illustrated this: [Why does C# execute Math.Sqrt() more slowly than VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025968/why-does-c-execute-math-sqrt-more-slowly-than-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the condition in a for loop is checked on every iteration.  If the function you're calling there is at all expensive, then you should definitely store the value in a variable.  However, if you have a short loop, it really won't make a difference.